# Package cv2 crashes after a while

Tags: python, opencv

I've a webcam filming my water meter and a Python script on a raspberry is converting this picture in several steps so that i could read out the consumption.

Now my problem. After a while (sometimes it runs for weeks, sometimes after some hours and today sometimes after minutes) I'm getting this error:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/backup/water.py", line 26, in <module>
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-wheel-b0jd8w40/opencv-contrib-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

I read that this could be caused by an interruption of the webcam connection.

I tried it with an try - exception handling. But it doesn't work.
What can I do that the script doesnt crash if there is an error?
Would there be an solution like "if there is an error, wait 30 secs restart the whole python code" or something like this? Or another solution that just reconnect the webcam stream if there is an error and tries this as long as it works again.

The whole code including my last attempt to handle this problem looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import time

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://syno:xxxx@xxxx:554/Sms=3.unicast")
client = InfluxDBClient(host="xxxx", port=8086,
                        username="xxxx", password="xxxx", ssl=False, verify_ssl=False)

send_water = 0

while (True):
    try:
        ret, frame = vcap.read()

        cv2.circle(frame, (485, 255), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (600, 250), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (480, 390), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (600, 390), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        pts1 = np.float32([[485, 255], [600, 250], [480, 390], [600, 390]])
        pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [300, 0], [0, 300], [300, 300]])

        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        (thresh, frame) = cv2.threshold(frame, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        frame = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, matrix, (300, 300))

        cv2.circle(frame, (148, 142), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        frame = cv2.warpPolar(frame, (100, 200), (148, 142),
                              frame.shape[1] * .4, cv2.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR)
        waterlevel = frame.sum(axis=1).argmax()

        if not "last_water" in locals():
            last_water = waterlevel

        if waterlevel - last_water >= 0:
            waterdif = 10 * (waterlevel - last_water) / 200
            last_water = waterlevel
        elif waterlevel < last_water & last_water - waterlevel < 171:
            waterdif = 10 * (200 + waterlevel - last_water) / 200
            last_water = waterlevel
        else:
            waterdif = 0

        send_water = send_water + waterdif

        if send_water >= 0.25:
            current_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
            client.switch_database("water")
            json_body = [
                {
                    "measurement": "Consump",
                    "time": current_time,
                    "fields": {
                        "Current_Consump": send_water
                    }
                }
            ]
            client.write_points(json_body)
            print(send_water)
            send_water = 0

        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        cv2.waitKey(1)
    except:
        print("Error!")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        time.sleep(10)
        pass

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing that you should do is to check the `ret`. From [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html):

> `cap.read()` returns a `bool` (True/False). If the frame is read correctly, it will be True

If it is `False` you have several alternatives: continue the while loop, sleep for some time, terminate the program, release the video capture and create it again, etc. You can also combine them.

Example to release the video capture and create it again:

```python
        ret, frame = vcap.read()

        if not ret:
            vcap.release()
            vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://syno:xxxx@xxxx:554/Sms=3.unicast")
            continue
```